# Calculating inverse Mod where Mod is not prime

Tags: algorithm, modulus, chinese-remainder-theorem

I want to calculate value of

F(N) = (F(N-1) * [((N-R+1)^(N-R+1))/(R^R)]) mod M for given values of N,R and M.

Here A^B shows A power B and NOT any Bitwise operation

Here M need not to be prime.How to approach this question?Please help because if M was prime that it would not have beed so difficult to find inverse of R^R mod M.

But as M can be any value ranging from 1 to 10^9.I am not able to tackle this problem.

N can be between 1 and 10^5 and R is less than or equal to N.

Comment: Are you sure that R^R divides your numerator evenly?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know somehow that the result of the division is an integer:

As N and R are small, you can do this by computing the prime factorisation of N-R+1 and R.

If we know that `R=p^a...q^b` then `R^R = p^(Ra)...q^(Rb)`.

Similarly you can work out the power of each prime in `(N-R+1)^(N-R+1)`.

Subtract the powers of the primes in `R^R` from the powers of the primes in `(N-R+1)^(N-R+1)` gives you the powers of each prime in the result.

You can then use a standard binary exponentiation routine to compute the result modulo M with no inverses required.

Comment: Actually Its something like this F(N) = F(N-1)[((N-R+1)^(N-R+1))/(R^R)] mod M .Though i get your point but how to keep this for F(N-1) term also ?